# How to use "Search Github using Query" task

Tags: power-automate, powerapps

I'm trying to use the "Search Github using Query" task:

[image]

But I get an error no matter what I fill in as a query.

This is the response:

```
    "body": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Parse error on \"is\" (IDENTIFIER) at [1, 1]",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the output of the query `is:open` and also `Microsoft` separately?

Comment: Both queries give the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Search Github using Query" action in Power Automate takes a GraphQL string.

For example, you can try:

```
{
  repository(owner: "microsoft", name: "charticulator") {
    issues(states:[OPEN], first:5) {
      nodes{
        number
        title
        state
        url
      }
      pageInfo { hasNextPage, endCursor}
    }
  }
}
```

You can use the [GitHub GraphQL API Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) to build and try out.

Alternatively, you may want to use `Get all issues of a repository` or `Find issues by state and keyword` actions.